# Codeigniter 3 unserialize(): Error (cache_file)

Tags: php, session, caching, codeigniter-3

Every now and then I see the following error. (on any page)

I am using the cache_file system.

Error Ex.:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 2629626 of 2629632 bytes

Filename: drivers/Cache_file.php

Line Number: 275
```

And sometimes members experience log out as well. Session issue...

I tried CI4 update, no solution.

I also updated the cache driver files to the latest version CI3, there was no solution.

I tried different server, no solution.